# Exporting image to excel through HTML

Tags: html, coldfusion

I have an image which is converted through canvas object and placed in div tag which is in table tag and I am trying to export same table to excel using coldfusion. Below is the code:

```
<cfset excel='y'>
<cfif isDefined('excel')>
  <CFHEADER NAME="content-disposition" VALUE="attachment; filename=ProjectsList.xls">
  <CFCONTENT TYPE="application/vnd.ms-excel">  
</cfif>
<table>
   <tr><td>Field 1</td> <td>Field 2</td> </tr>
   <tr><td>Data 1</td>  <td>Data 2</td>  </tr>
   <tr><td colspan="2"><div id="DataImg"></div></td></tr>
</table>
```

I have one more div tag which has some content and I am taking a screenshot of it through HTML2canvas and converted it into image and placed in another div(with Id="DataImg"). Jquery code for Image:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var element = $("#div_Status"); 
        var getCanvas;
        html2canvas(element, {
            onrendered: function (canvas) {
                var image = new Image();
                image.src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
                $("#DataImg").append(image);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

I want the image placed in DataImg div tag to come up in excel but as of now only text content is coming and not image.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
workBook = SpreadSheetNew("Data", true);
spreadsheetaddimage(workbook,"d:\folders go here\filename.jpg","1,1,2,2");
SpreadSheetWrite(workBook,completefileName, true);
```

Comment: Hi Dan, I do not have any physical path for an image. It is created through JQuery as mentioned above in question.

Comment: That would be the classic javascript runs on client, coldfusion runs on server problem.

Comment: You can still save the data using CF, but you'll need to use ajax as well. Example: Since you're already using jQuery, use jQuery ajax to call a facade CFC with the base64 data as an attribute value, then save the data from there into an image file.

Comment: Hi @JeffCoughlin Let's say we have the base64 image code and don't want to write the file to the disk (safety precautions, space, extra garbage files, etc.) and we need to just embed in Excel and forget about those files?